# dart: How to read a longer line via stdin.readLineSync() than 1024 characters

Tags: dart

```
void main() {
  while (true) {
    var s = stdin.readLineSync();
    if (s != null) {
      print('Length: ${s.length}');
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this program, it is not possible for there to be more than 1023 characters in a line. The maximum can be 1023 characters and the next character must be enter. This restriction is actually in the stdin.readByteSync() function, which stdin.readLineSync() calls internally.

I'm working on a program that processes data via stdin, and this restriction forces me to far more complicated communication via http or via files or invent a protocol that will split a long line into a group of shorter lines.

Comment: On what platform?  I ran your code on my Ubuntu 22.04 x64 system, and I do not see the limitation you describe.

Comment: I do see a limit of 4095 characters when I run it interactively, but I don't see a limit when piping input in.

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on OS. MacOS 1024. Windows 256. Linux (it depends)..